# Do you recognize these numbers related to the higher Airy equations?

Tags: differential-equations, integer-sequences

I'm studying the higher Airy equations
$$\left[\big({-}\tfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\big)^{n-1} - y\right] \psi = 0$$
under a coordinate transformation. The interesting coefficients $c_n^{(1)}, \ldots, c_n^{(n-1)}$ of the transformed equation can be written as $c_n^{(k)} = C_n^{(k)}/n^k$, where the $C_n^{(k)}$ are integers. Some examples are shown below. I'd like to have a description of these numbers which is easier to work with than the one I just gave—maybe a formula, a recurrence relation, or a link to some known series. Can you find one?

#### Examples

$$\begin{array}{r|rrrrrrrrrr}
n & C_n^{(1)} & C_n^{(2)} & C_n^{(3)} & C_n^{(4)} & C_n^{(5)} & C_n^{(6)} & C_n^{(7)} & C_n^{(8)} & C_n^{(9)} & C_n^{(10)} \\
\hline
3 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
4 & 6 & 5 & 10 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
5 & 10 & 15 & 75 & 231 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
6 & 15 & 35 & 315 & 2324 & 9576 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
7 & 21 & 70 & 980 & 12635 & 121275 & 623645 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
8 & 28 & 126 & 2520 & 49455 & 812700 & 9540180 & 58715280 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
9 & 36 & 210 & 5670 & 156345 & 3849930 & 76186495 & 1053966375 & 7547514975 & 0 & 0 \\
10 & 45 & 330 & 11550 & 424347 & 14501025 & 424775120 & 9786084000 & 155612160704 & 1270453824640 & 0 \\
11 & 55 & 495 & 21780 & 1026333 & 46263987 & 1862118720 & 62878315500 & 1648717189119 & 29595505782843 & 271252029133449 \\
12 & 66 & 715 & 38610 & 2267265 & 129999870 & 6845823985 & 315047282550 & 12009319021700 & 352582189759800 & 7047265192531200 \\
13 & 78 & 1001 & 65065 & 4654650 & 330269940 & 21970828880 & 1313812259760 & 67787865220075 & 2873487616249250 & 93292693244926175 \\
14 & 91 & 1365 & 105105 & 8993985 & 772837065 & 63249492735 & 4750039168875 & 316601172587700 & 18059450810801400 & 841617929840688000 \\
15 & 105 & 1820 & 163800 & 16514498 & 1688737050 & 166527399610 & 15308254533000 & 1274980294494907 & 93476069152170705 & 5832466394299114570 \\
16 & 120 & 2380 & 247520 & 29031002 & 3482086608 & 406825078660 & 44863414596000 & 4553664549120687 & 415346748385713144 & 33163214347357486392 \\
17 & 136 & 3060 & 364140 & 49148190 & 6830902260 & 932485824270 & 121364647554150 & 14720662805673825 & 1630006296346127700 & 161290219883701258350 \\
18 & 153 & 3876 & 523260 & 80514210 & 12832689870 & 2022935014100 & 306577384052940 & 43737476639431575 & 5767594256002003425 & 690458001393795835200 \\
19 & 171 & 4845 & 736440 & 128130870 & 23209458930 & 4182845523220 & 729797973996000 & 120864258833943625 & 18689183207667197225 & 2656343035062571279425
\end{array}$$

#### Partial results

The first coefficients seem to be the triangular numbers:
$$C_n^{(1)} = \frac{n(n-1)}{2} = \left(\begin{matrix} n \\ 2 \end{matrix}\right).$$
The last coefficients can be written nicely with a [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) (this one is apparent from the coordinate transformation):
$$\begin{align*}
C_n^{(n-1)} & = (n-2)(2n-3)(3n-4) \cdots [(n-2)n - (n-1)] \\
& = (n-1)^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^{\underline{n-1}}.
\end{align*}$$
The second and third coefficients seem to be nice multiples of the previous ones, which can also be written with binomial coefficients:
$$\begin{alignat*}{2}
C_n^{(2)} &\;=\;& \frac{(n+1)(n-2)}{12} C_n^{(1)} &\;=\;& \left(\begin{matrix} n+1 \\ 4 \end{matrix}\right) \\
C_n^{(3)} &\;=\;& \frac{n(n-3)}{2} C_n^{(2)} &\;=\;& \left(\begin{matrix} n+1 \\ 2 \end{matrix}\right) \left(\begin{matrix} n \\ 4 \end{matrix}\right).
\end{alignat*}$$
The later coefficients can't be expressed so simply, because they have prime factors much larger than $n$. For instance,
$$\begin{align*}
83 & \mid C_6^{(4)} \\
157 & \mid C_8^{(4)} & 43 & \mid C_9^{(5)} \\
1489 & \mid C_9^{(4)} & 97 & \mid C_9^{(5)} \\
167 & \mid C_{10}^{(4)} \\
1481 & \mid C_{11}^{(4)}
\end{align*}$$
Guessing around these factors, I found the expression
$$C_n^{(5)} = \frac{21n(3n+1)(11n-2)}{16} \left(\begin{matrix} n+1 \\ 7 \end{matrix}\right),$$
which I've checked up to $n = 18$. If there's a similar expression for $C_n^{(4)}$, it'll probably look even weirder.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, great idea! I've added enough rows to interpolate $C_n^{(6)}$.

Comment: Looks like $$\begin{eqnarray*}
C_n^{(3)} &=& \frac{(n+1)^{\underline{5}} n}{48} \\
C_n^{(4)} &=& \frac{(n+1)^{\underline{6}} (73n^2 + 5n - 2) }{5760} \\
C_n^{(5)} &=& \frac{(n+1)^{\underline{7}} (11n - 2) (3n + 1) n}{3840} \\
C_n^{(6)} &=& \frac{(n+1)^{\underline{8}} (5n - 1) (3625n^3 + 1579n^2 - 10n - 16)}{2903040} \\
C_n^{(7)} &=& \frac{(n+1)^{\underline{9}} (5n - 1)(13n - 2)(5n + 1)(17n + 8)n}{1161216} \\
C_n^{(8)} &=& \frac{(n+1)^{\underline{10}} (5233001n^6 + 2061027n^5 - 669137n^4 - 136231n^3 + 29568n^2 + 892n - 144)}{1393459200} \\
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: If the pattern $C_{-2}^{(k)} = \frac{(2k-1)!!}3$ continues, there are enough terms to guess $$\begin{eqnarray*}C_n^{(9)} &=& \binom{n}{10} \frac{7n(n+1)(7n+1)(173183n^5 + 56092n^4 - 31707n^3 - 2932n^2 + 1900n - 144)}{768}  \\
C_n^{(10)} &=& \binom{n}{11} \frac{(n+1)(927777937n^8 + 496914044n^7 - 129876342n^6 - 58362832n^5 + 10245673n^4 + 1739364n^3 - 266180n^2 - 6160n + 768)}{9216}\end{eqnarray*}$$ and it's looking as though even and odd $k$ should be considered separately: $C_n^{(2j+1)} = \binom{n}{2j+2} (2j-1)n(n+1) ((2j-1)n + 1)P_j(n)$ for $j>1$, $C_n^{(2j)} = \binom{n}{2j+1}(n+1)Q_j(n)$

Comment: @PeterTaylor: Aha! Writing $C_n^{(k)} = (n+1)^{\underline{k+2}}\;R^{(k)}$, as you suggest, we get $$\begin{alignat*}{6}R^{(2)}&=&\tfrac{1}{24}\\ R^{(3)}&=&\tfrac{1}{48}n\\ R^{(4)}&=& \tfrac{73}{5760}n^2&+&\tfrac{1}{1152}n&-&\tfrac{1}{2880}\\ R^{(5)}&=&\tfrac{11}{1280}n^3&+& \tfrac{1}{768}n^2&-&\tfrac{1}{1920}n\\ R^{(6)}&=&\tfrac{3625}{580608}n^4&+&\tfrac{61}{41472}n^3&-&\tfrac{181}{322560}n^2&-&\tfrac{1}{41472}n&+&\tfrac{1}{181440}\end{alignat*}$$ The leading coefficients are "fractions appearing in a generalization of Carleman's inequality," listed in the OEIS as A249276 and A249277.

Comment: @Vectornaut Just a heads up: the examples aren't depicted in math mode (at least on my phone)

Comment: @MaxMuller, that's strange! Do all the other formulas show up in MathJax? The table of examples compiles correctly with LaTeX, and appears correctly on my phone and laptop.

Comment: @Vectornaut Yes, all of the other ones look good. I use an iphone, perhaps that's related